# Intellij shortcut to create code snippet for testing

Tags: intellij-idea

Is there any shortcut/setting/plugin available in intellij where I can create test data structure with some default values ?

e.g.

```
Map<String,String> stringMap = new HashMap();
stringMap.put("1","A")
stringMap.put("2","B")
stringMap.put("3","C")
```

I dont want to type all of the above as I want to test very quick with any values.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the '[Live Templates](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-live-templates.html)' functionality, for instance. A guide on how to create such a template can be found [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-editing-live-templates.html).

> Use live templates to insert common constructs into your code, such as
>   loops, conditions, various declarations, or print statements.
>
> To expand a code snippet, type the corresponding template abbreviation
>   and press `Tab`

In the screenshot below, I created a custom template called `smap` in the 'other' template group, added your code to it and selected the language (Java) that this template can be applied to.

Once in the editor, I can type `smap` and a pop-up will appear suggesting me to use the existing template to replace the abbreviation with code. Hitting `Tab` or `Enter` will perform the replacement.

[image]